# mongodb sum of data last seven days data need date object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i trying to find day wise sum of the last seven days records. but i couldn't get proper date object.

sample code

```
 db.collection('history').aggregate([
                               {$match:{ts:{$gt: moment().subtract(6, 'days').startOf('day')._d,$lt: moment().endOf('day')._d}}},
                    { $group: {
                            _id : { day: { $dayOfMonth: "$ts" }, 
                                 month: { $month: "$ts" },
                                year: { $year: "$ts" } },
                            EGeneration: { '$sum': '$EGeneration' },
                            EConsumption: { '$sum': '$EConsumption' }
                        }
                    }
                ], function (err, datas) {
                    if (err || !datas) console.log(err);
                    else {
                        console.log(datas);
                    }
                })
```

**in that _id i need proper date object**

sample data

```
{
"_id" : {
    "deviceId" : 20016,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-06-08T09:58:37.000Z")
},
"ts" : ISODate("2018-06-08T09:58:37.000Z"),
"EGeneration" : 0.00092393,
"EConsumption" : 0
```

}

{
    "_id" : {
        "deviceId" : 20019,
        "ts" : ISODate("2018-06-09T09:58:37.000Z")
    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-06-09T09:58:37.000Z"),

```
"EGeneration" : 0.00092393,
"EConsumption" : 0
```

}

{
    "_id" : {
        "deviceId" : 20028,
        "ts" : ISODate("2018-06-09T09:58:37.000Z")
    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-06-09T09:58:37.000Z"),

```
"EGeneration" : 0.00092393,
"EConsumption" : 0
```

}

sample output

```
[ { _id: { day: 9, month: 6, year: 2018 },
EGeneration: 0.00184786,
EConsumption: 0 },
```

{ _id: { day: 8, month: 6, year: 2018 },
    EGeneration: 0.00092393,
    EConsumption: 0 } ]

Comment: post your sample collection and output please

Answer (score 0):

To get the final output with ISODate format , convert the ISODate to string removing the time part. Reconvert the date as string to ISODate , Followed by aggregation

```
db.history.aggregate([
   {$project:{"timestamp":"$ts","gen":"$EGeneration","con":"$EConsumption",diff_msecs:{$subtract:[new ISODate(),"$ts"]}}},
   {$project:{"timestamp":1,"con":1,"gen":1,diff_days:{$divide:["$diff_msecs",1000*60*60*24]}}},
   {$match:{"diff_days":{"$lte":7}}},
   {"$project":{"con":1,"gen":1,"dateString":{$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$timestamp" }}}},
   {"$project":{"_id":0,"con":1,"gen":1,"datewithouttime":{"$dateFromString":{"dateString": "$dateString"}}}},
   {"$group":{"_id":"$datewithouttime","EGeneration":{"$sum":"$gen"},"EConsumption":{"$sum":"$con"}}}])
```

Output would be :

```
{ "_id" : ISODate("2018-06-09T00:00:00Z"), "EGeneration" : 0.00184786, "EConsumption" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2018-06-08T00:00:00Z"), "EGeneration" : 0.00092393, "EConsumption" : 0 }
```